# Ambiguous truth value for meshgrid and user-defined functions using if-statement

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let's assume that I have a function `f(x,y)` being sufficiently smooth. Yet some values only exist in the sense of a limit. Take e.g. `sin(x)/ x` the value for `x=0` only exists in the limit x -> 0.
In the general case I handle this with an `if` statement.

If I use this in a plot with `meshgrid` I get an error message:

*ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()*

Do I really have to run two `for` loops to fill an z-array or is there a way to use `meshgrid`?

minimal working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def test(x,y):
    a=1.0/(1+x*x)
    if y==0:
        b=1
    else:
        b=np.sin(y)/y
    return(a * b)

if __name__=='__main__':
    X = linspace(-5, 5, 100)
    Y = linspace(-5, 5, 100)
    X,Y = meshgrid(X, Y)
    Z =test(X,Y)

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection='3d')
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=8, cstride=8, alpha=0.25)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assign values only to some elements of a Numpy array you can simply use indexing,

```
import numpy as np

def test(x, y):
    a = 1.0/(1+x*x)
    b = np.ones(y.shape)
    mask = (y!=0)
    b[mask] = np.sin(y[mask])/y[mask]
    return a*b
```

Comment: That is an interesting solution. If I get it right, the exception is put as sort of default value, than the rest is evaluated. I have to play with this. How would you generalize this to multiple exceptions with different values and also exceptions that depend on   `x` and `y` at the same time? (Let's say e.g. `if y==0: return 1` and `if x**2+y**2==1: return 2` otherwise use formula `g(x,y)`)

Comment: Well yes, here `b` is initialised to 1 as it simplifies this particular problem. In general you can just initialise it with the default value, and then set only selected elements with a mask (e.g. `b[y==0] = 1;  b[x**2+y**2 !=1] = 3; b[(y==1) & (x>0)] = 4`, etc) See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing