# Applying a function to meshgrids only under select polygon criteria?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, logic, shapely

My question is similar to this post but I'm having some trouble adapting it:
[Ambiguous truth value for meshgrid and user-defined functions using if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148725/ambiguous-truth-value-for-meshgrid-and-user-defined-functions-using-if-statement)

Essentially, I would like the conditional statement to not look like this:

```
import numpy as np

def test(x, y):
    a = 1.0/(1+x*x)
    b = np.ones(y.shape)
    mask = (y!=0)
    b[mask] = np.sin(y[mask])/y[mask]
    return a*b
```

Rather, the "mask" to depend on whether x,y lie within a certain polygon. So every value in the resulting array is a 1, but a polygon between 4 values is generated. I only want the function to apply to points from the 2 meshgrid inputs (X,Y) which lay inside the polygon

x and y are real numbers that can be negative.

I'm not sure how to pass in the array items as singular values.

I ultimately want to plot Z on a colour plot
Thanks

i.e. points within a polygon undergo a transformation, points outside the polygon remain as 1
For example, I would expect my function to look like this

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
def f(x, y, poly):
    a = 1.0/(1+x*x)
    b = np.ones(y.shape)
    mask = (Point(x,y).within(poly) == True)
    b[mask] = a*b
    return b
```

x and y are meshgrids of arbitrary dimensions

I should add that I get the following error:
"only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

X and Y are generated and the function is called via

```
coords = [(0, 0), (4,0), (4,4), (0,4)]
poly = Polygon(coords)
x = np.linspace(0,10, 11, endpoint = True) # x intervals
y = np.linspace(0,10,11, endpoint = True) # y intervals
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

Z = f(X, Y, poly)
```

Thanks!

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "meshgrid_understanding.py", line 28, in <module>
    Z = f(X, Y, poly)
  File "meshgrid_understanding.py", line 16, in f
    mask = (Point(x,y).within(poly) != True)
  File "C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\point.py", line 48, in __init__
    self._set_coords(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\point.py", line 137, in _set_coords
    self._geom, self._ndim = geos_point_from_py(tuple(args))
  File "C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\point.py", line 214, in geos_point_from_py
    dx = c_double(coords[0])
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matplotlib has a function that accepts an array of points. Demo:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.path import Path

coords = [(0, 0), (4,0), (4,4), (0,4)]

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 11, endpoint=True)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, 11, endpoint=True)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

points = np.c_[X.ravel(), Y.ravel()]
mask = Path(coords).contains_points(points).reshape(X.shape)
```

Comment: it works for assigning values to the b[mask] i.e. b[mask] = 3, but I can't seem to assigning the value to be a function of its location. For example, I want each point in b[mask] to be a function of its x and y coordinate. I just get an error if i do it via b[mask] = 3x+2y etc

Comment: I solved it actually, sort of by using this. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an array to the function `Point` that accepts single values.

Comment: That's the point, I am not sure how do provide single values that once the function is complete, correspond to their respective x,y pair